# AddEventListener in loop for dynamic soundbar

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm not sure how to implement this, but here is my problem:

I load buttons into a loop and want a sound from an XML file to play for every button click. I tried to add a sound object to an array, but I can't change the name of the sound object dynamically so it overwrites all the other objects.

```
for(var i:int=0;i<mainclass.xml.Value.length();i++){
    var button:Knopf=new Knopf(mainclass.xml.Value[i].@bez);
    var sound:Sound=new Sound(new URLRequest(mainclass.xml.Value[i].fad));
    var array:Array=new Array();
    var array2:Array=new Array();
    start.addChild(button);
    array.push(sound);
    button.name="button"+i;
    array2.push(button.name);
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click);
    button.x=xwert;
    xwert+=100;
function click(event:MouseEvent):void {
        trace(array[0].play());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are overwritting/resetting your array at every loop

Comment: Yes i know because i dont have a dynamic variable name thats the main problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what @Eric means is if you declare the array inside the 'for':

```
var array:Array=new Array();
```

Then the array is going to be empty in every loop

I suggest this code, please note, I added a 'preparing stuff' block of code to simulate the environment you are running your code, basically, I created an object mainclass with a xml property inside, and a 'start' movieclip added to the stage. I also had to change your Knopf class for a simple textField but the idea is the same.

In order to store the sound objects, instead of an array, I used an object 'sounds' but look how it is defined before the loop, the same way is recommended to initialise xwert variable before the loop.

click function should be defined also outside the loop, you only need one listener for all buttons, this listener will know what button is the one was clicked (event.target) then, knowing its name, we can access the 'sounds' object using that name.

The code is working in my computer having a 'click.mp3' sound in the same directory, because is how it's defined in my sample xml: click.mp3

```
//Preparing stuff
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
var mainclass = {
    xml: new XML("<xml><Value bez='Button A'><fad>click.mp3</fad></Value><Value bez='Button B'><fad>click.mp3</fad></Value><Value bez='Button C'><fad>click.mp3</fad></Value></xml>")
}
var start = new MovieClip();
this.addChild(start);
//End of Pre-stuff


//Code to implement
var xwert: int = 0; //Initialize xwert variable
var sounds:Object = {}

for (var i: int = 0; i < mainclass.xml.Value.length(); i++) {
    var button: TextField = new TextField();
    button.text = mainclass.xml.Value[i].@bez;
    var sound: Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest(mainclass.xml.Value[i].fad));
    start.addChild(button);
    button.name = "button" + i;
    sounds[button.name] = sound;
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click);
    button.x = xwert;
    xwert += 100;
}
function click(event: MouseEvent): void {
    trace(sounds[event.currentTarget.name]);
    sounds[event.target.name].play();
}
```

EDIT: Changet target by currentTarget

Comment: have exact the same code and it looks like it should work but he throws `TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at Soundboard/click()[C:\Users\Philipp\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\Soundboard\src\Soundboard.mxml:41]`                                          
On Line 41 `sounds[event.target.name].play()`

Btw i work with FlashBuilder and without MovieClip

Comment: the trace only prints undefined but without sounds it prints instance+number.

Comment: Are you sure URLRequest(mainclass.xml.Value[i].fad) is really loading a sound? I mean, are they valid URLs with valid sound files?

Comment: Wha happens if you trace only sounds object?

Comment: Try using currentTarget instead of target.

Comment: yeah that was is needed currentTarget instead of target thanks a lot